# SSH check to remote gerrit with server name not working

Tags: macos, gerrit, openssh

**Environment:-**

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.4
BuildVersion:   19E287
```

**Problem:-**

`SSH` connection check to remote gerrit server with `server name not working`. where as it `works with IP address`

```
 With IP Address:-

  ssh -T -p 29418 ramesh@40.41.42.43

  ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****
  Hi Ramesh, you have successfully connected over SSH.

  Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

  git clone ssh://ramesh@gerrit.server.com:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git
```

With server name:-

```
ssh -Tvvv -p 29418 ramesh@gerrit.server.com
    OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to gerrit.server.com port 29418.
```

i have added the server name in MAC OS's host file but still it is hanging. Is it something issue with OpenSSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS upgraded to ProductVersion: 10.15.5 and in this it is working fine.